# Pass data to GlobalControllerExceptionHandler in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

My project needs to build a file containing logs and load it to S3.

To do this, whenever a Spring Batch job is ran, I create a file like this:

```
String startTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
new File(startTime + "_error_logs");
```

I then add it to a set of `JobParameters` which get passed to my `JobLauncher` like this:

```
SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
   .addString("startTime", startTime)
   .toJobParameters();
jobLauncher.run(getJob(), param);
```

Then, throughout the project, I want to be able to access this job parameter. For example, I can get it in my `JobCompletionNotificationListener` class which in the `afterJob` function, takes `JobExecution` as a parameter, meaning that I can do this:

```
String startTime = jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("startTime");
```

However, in the `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler` class, I don't have access to this `JobExecution` object meaning that I cannot get hold of the `startTime` parameter.

Is there anyway I can pass data to it? Or is there a better approach to this problem? I know that I will have the same issue in other classes. Other approaches I have thought of won't work either, for example, storing the String in a file won't work because then if another job is ran in parallel, it will become confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a `JobExplorer` in your `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler` and query for the `jobExecution` you are interested in. Once you get a handle to the execution you want, you can get the parameter as you mentioned:

```
String startTime = jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("startTime");
```

Comment: How can I know what jobExecution I want though? If there are three of the same type of jobs running at the same time, I still would need to get the correct execution id which takes me back to the same problem I was having before. If job 1 failed, I have no way to know which of the three jobs failed at the point of getting to `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler`.

Comment: `If there are three of the same type of jobs running at the same time`: that's not possible, only one job execution of a job instance is allowed to be running at a time, otherwise you will get a `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`. Unless you mean 3 job executions of 3 **different** job instances running at the same time. In all cases, I guess you know at least the name of the job for which you want to get executions, in which case you can use `JobExplorer#findRunningJobExecutions` or get job instances with `JobExplorer#getJobInstances` and then look for the corresponding executions.